# How can I split a Javascript string into sentences that are less than 140 characters?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, twitter

I'm working in a Javascript environment with a string that I would eventually like to tweet out via Twitter bot. The problem is, sometimes this string is two short sentences, and sometimes it's several very long sentences.

Example strings I'm working with:

> **Short:**
>
> > "Blah foo. Not so much foo."
>
> **Long:**
>
> > "Lots of blah foo. So many foo. There is a no way that this foo would fit in one tweet. The characters in this tweet need to be made into a multiple tweets. In fact, there are 189 characters."

I also add onto the beginning and end, so it ends up looking like this:

> **Short:**
>
> > "Today: Blah foo. Not so much foo. #hashtag"

I would like the longer-than-140 string to be split up into several tweets.

> **Long Tweet 1:**
>
> > "Today: Lots of blah foo. So many foo. There is a no way that this foo would fit in one tweet. #hashtag"
>
> **Long Tweet 2:**
>
> > "The characters in this tweet need to be made into a multiple tweets. In fact, there are 189 characters. #hashtag"

The way I see it, I could either `string.split()` up the entire string into an array of sentences and loop through them to build each tweet, or I could use Regex to select and split up the long string into multiple just-under-140-character strings.

Which method would be more efficient? I assume it would be the Regex option. How would I go about implementing that solution?

Comment: This is (pretty much) the same as splitting an array into bins or any other large-list-to-smaller-lists algorithm, since JS treats strings as read-only arrays. Not sure if that will help you find an answer, but it's worth looking into.

Comment: How much do you care about the multiple tweets making sense? If you are just splitting sentence and posting them separately do they still make sense without the full context?

Comment: It's not as easy as you might guess - what if someone inputs a domain name (`blabla.com`) or an email address (`john.lee@hooker.com`) - how do you want to deal with the dots here?

Comment: I suppose we could split based on "dot space"? (". ")?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A naive but simple way would be a regex like

```
/.{1,140}\./g
```

Example:

```js
text = "Lots of blah foo. So many foo. There is a no way that this foo would fit in one tweet. The characters in this tweet need to be made into a multiple tweets. In fact, there are 189 characters."
m = text.match(/.{1,140}\./g)

for (let tweet of m)
    console.log(tweet, tweet.length)
```

Comment: This is a really interesting solution. Does this break if there are decimals/periods somewhere that doesn't end a sentence?

Comment: I used `text.match(/.{1,139}\. /g)` and it's working brilliantly! Thanks much

Comment: Yes, it does break if there's stuff like "3.14" or "Mr. Smith" or "Y.M.C.A" - that's why I said "naive".

Comment: @xd1936: You could make it a bit less naive by adding a look-ahead for a space or the end of the string (e.g. `/.{1,140}\.(?=\s|$)/g`)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [];
var str = "Lots of blah foo. So many foo. There is a no way that this foo would fit in one tweet. The characters in this tweet need to be made into a multiple tweets. In fact, there are 189 characters.";
arr.push(str.substring(0, 140));
arr.push(str.substring(140));
```

Comment: My question was looking for the best way to split up the string into **sentences**, not just at 140 characters sharp :)

Comment: @xd1936 Basically the same. You are slitting string with native `string.substring` method, then store chunks in array with `arr.push` and looping it whenever you want.
If you want somehow split it by sentences, you can try to search for a dot in string, and split it by dots if dot is appears close to 140th.